# How to call a php file using mysql triggers, if hosted on AWS EC2?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, triggers, udf

I have hosted my application and database on AWS EC2 server. Now I want to run a php script using my sql triggers, I tried using UDFs but it seems that UDFs require permissions of accessing the O/S but AWS doesn't allow.

Comment: Is your database on EC2 or RDS?

Comment: @RyanVincent - it's via UDF called `sys_exec`. [Available UDFs](http://www.mysqludf.org/) and [sys at github](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme)

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks interesting.

Comment: @OP - how did you install that UDF? If you haven't installed it, what errors did you get while installing it?